# How to animate widget transparency in Qt4?

Tags: qt, qt4

I need to animate widget transparency.
It seems to me, that I should use [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/animation-overview.html#animating-qt-properties). But how could i define widget translucent? Should I use something [like this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering)?

Comment: what exactly you want?.. do you want to show animation on your widget? or you want to make your widget transparent

Answer (score 8):

There are two sub-answers to your question, from what I've played with at least:

1. If you want to set animate the opacity of a QWidget toplevel window, you can use QPropertyAnimation from 0 to 1 on the "windowOpacity" value. You might want to check the exact syntax since I'm using PyQt.
2. If you want to animate the opacity of a button or of a text label, this property won't work and you need to use QGraphicsWidgets. They inherit QGraphicsItem and so, they have `opacity`. Unfortunately, this means using proxy widgets QGrapgicsProxyWidget to keep normal widgets in sync with their graphics widget counterparts since QGraphicsWidget doesn't inherit QWidget. To find out more, check out the [Animation Framework Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/examples-animation.html), in particular the State Machine for how to use proxy widgets.

For `windowOpacity` animations:

`QPropertyAnimation animate = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "windowOpacity", this);`

`animate.setDuration(100); animate.setStartValue(1); animate.setEndValue(0);`
`animate.start();`

This will work only on systems that support some kind of Composite extension.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you!
Seems, that I should try the second way, cause I need to make my widgets (buttons, text, etc.) smoothly transparent on some event.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [`windowOpacity`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop) property in QWidget.  If that doesn't work, you may need to define your own property and use it in the paint event for your widget.